# Unauthorized Rovi TV Listings Service Soap 1.2

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, soapui

I am using soap UI to test the webservice by giving the credentials but its always displaying a message "unauthorized". Could any one please let me know why is this happening? I am trying to getServices.

http://developer.rovicorp.com/docs

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"     xmlns:typ="http://api.rovicorp.com/v9/common/types"     xmlns:lis="http://api.rovicorp.com/v9/listings">
 <soap:Header>
  <typ:AuthHeader>
     <typ:UserName>username</typ:UserName>
     <typ:Password>password</typ:Password>
  </typ:AuthHeader>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
  <lis:GetServices>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <lis:request>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <typ:ClientBatchId>?</typ:ClientBatchId>
        <lis:Locale>en-GB</lis:Locale>
        <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
        <lis:ServiceSearch>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <lis:PostalCode>?</lis:PostalCode>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <lis:CountryCode>GB</lis:CountryCode>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <lis:MSOId>?</lis:MSOId>
        </lis:ServiceSearch>
        <lis:ServiceId>?</lis:ServiceId>
        <lis:StartDate>2012-06-19</lis:StartDate>
        <lis:Duration>263521</lis:Duration>
     </lis:request>
   </lis:GetServices>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: http://api.rovicorp.com/v9/listingsservice.asmx?apikey=yourapikey

Comment: I have API key from Rovi

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely occurring because you have not provided an auth signature.  If you check your account in the Rovi portal there will be a Shared Secret associated with your API Key for that package.  You can calculate the signature by md5'ing your apikey, shared secret and epoch.  This link should help a little with that: http://prod-doc.rovicorp.com/mashery/index.php/Authentication-Code-Examples